# How to extract data from site with GeneralBots

Tags: bots

#GeneralBots - I'm currently trying to make a bot that brings everyday information about currency from different countries and cryptos and return that as a table. How could I access different sites and compare the rates?

I'm in the process of development.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on General Bots conversational Web Automation. So the user informs the proposal code for example, a login and search is done. And the data is retrieved from table with a single FIND keyword command. So you can do this several times as you want, mix data and produce some Notification and Log as output operations.

The complete .gbdialog reference is found on [BotBook](https://github.com/GeneralBots/BotBook/blob/master/book/chapter-05-gbdialog-reference.md).

Check out an example:

```
REM Asks for basic information.
TALK “Please, what is the code?” 
HEAR proposal
TALK “Thanks, I'll check that for you... Just a moment, please.” 

REM Performs login to the web site.
OPEN https://domain/login
SET “#login“, “user” 
SET “#senha“ , “password” 
CLICK “[name=login]“ 

REM Go to a page that contains an HTML table with data after a search
OPEN https://domain/data  
SET “#code“, proposal 
CLICK “[name=search]“ 
 
REM Get data with FIND keyword and answers the person.
list = FIND "#tableWithData" 
row  = list[1] 
TALK "The proposal status is " + row.Status
```

You can even use General Bots Data Analytics to create custom charts from that data like this:

[Conversational Data Analytics example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7mog.png)